# Nginx: rewrite url with keep request head

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

What I want to do is:

If the file I request is not on my disk, the nginx will request from real server, here is my `.htaccess` file rule, I want convert it to nginx rule, so the result is：

> ```
> RewriteEngine on
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/js/$0 [P]
> ```

```
    location /js/ {
        root   E://Work/master;

        if (!-e $request_filename){
            rewrite ^(.*)$ http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/$1 redirect;
       }            
    }
```

but this will cause two problem:

1. If I request `test.com/js/test.js` it will redirect to the `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx//js/sea1.2.js` **in my browser**! but the real server could refuse the request cuz I not use the `test.com` domain, and return `404`. so how can I let the nginx request from real server in background and keep the origin request header information at least keep the domain.**Just like the `Apache` did.**
2. As you mentioned above, the redirect result is `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx//js/sea1.2.js`, there is double slash before `js`. How can I fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

`404` means not found, change your config:

```
location /js/ {
    root   E://Work/master;

    if (!-e $request_filename){
        rewrite ^(.*)$ http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx$1 redirect;
   }            
}
```

the redirect result will be `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/js/sea1.2.js`, this will make it acts like `Apache`

Answer (score 0):

I assume the `[P]` flag meant proxy, also [avoiding nginx's `if`](http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil), here's my answer

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @proxy;
}
location @proxy {
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/$request_uri;
}
```